# I want to show Title, Description and Price in my cardview+RecyclerView, while it shows only Title

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to show Title , Description and Price but it only shows Title everywhere in output screen, Please help me. Thanks in advance.

I have created two activities , 1st is Fertilizers.java and 2nd is MyAdapter.java.
 My XML is working Properly while I think my adapter class has some issue due to which i,m not able to get my required output.

Fertilizers.java code is here :

```
        public class Fertilizers extends AppCompatActivity {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        List<FertilizersData> myFertilizersList;
        FertilizersData mFertilizersData;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fertilizers);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Fertilizers.this, 1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        myFertilizersList = new ArrayList<>();
        mFertilizersData = new FertilizersData("Urea Fertilizer","Urea is a concentrated straight nitrogenous fertilizer that contains 46% nitrogen, which is a major plant nutrient. Nitrogen is a vital component of chlorophyll which is necessary for the photosynthesis process. It is applied to promote vegetative growth of crops and orchards in splits (basal & top-dressing).","Rs.1000",R.drawable.urea_fertilizer);
     //   myFertilizersList.add(mFertilizersData);

        mFertilizersData = new FertilizersData("D.A.P","Diammonium phosphate (DAP) is the world’s most widely used phosphorus fertilizer. It’s made from two common constituents in the fertilizer industry, and its relatively high nutrient content and excellent physical properties make it a popular choice in farming and other industries.","Rs.1500",R.drawable.dap_fertilizer);
      //  myFertilizersList.add(mFertilizersData);

        mFertilizersData = new FertilizersData("Nitro Phos","Sarsabz Nitrophos (NP) is a granulated fertilizer in which each grain has equal amounts of Phosphorus (P) 20% & Nitrogen (N) 22%. In addition to this, NP being a highly acidic product with a pH of 3.5, is the most suitable fertilizer for soils that have a high pH and are alkaline in nature.","Rs.2700",R.drawable.nitro_phos);
        myFertilizersList.add(mFertilizersData);

        MyAdapter   myAdapter = new MyAdapter(Fertilizers.this,myFertilizersList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java,s code is here:

```
     package com.example.e_agriculture10;

     import android.content.Context;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
     import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
     import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

       import java.util.List;

      public class MyAdapter extends                                             RecyclerView.Adapter<FertilizerViewHolder>{

      private Context mContext;
      private List<FertilizersData> myFertilizersList;

      public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<FertilizersData>  myFertilizersList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.myFertilizersList = myFertilizersList;
    }

    @Override
    public FertilizerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_item,parent,false);
        return new FertilizerViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FertilizerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        FertilizerViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemImage());
        FertilizerViewHolder.mTitle.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());
        FertilizerViewHolder.mDescription.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());
        FertilizerViewHolder.mPrice.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myFertilizersList.size();
    }
}

class FertilizerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder      {

    static ImageView imageView;
    static TextView mTitle;
    static TextView mDescription;
    static TextView mPrice;
    static CardView mCardView;

    public FertilizerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        mPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myCardView);
    }
}
```

activity_fertilizers.xml is here:

```
package com.example.e_agriculture10;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
     import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FertilizerViewHolder>{

     private Context mContext;
      private List<FertilizersData> myFertilizersList;

     public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<FertilizersData>  myFertilizersList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.myFertilizersList = myFertilizersList;
      }

    @Override
     public FertilizerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup    parent, int viewType) {
         View mView =   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_item,parent,false);
         return new FertilizerViewHolder(mView);
     }

    @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FertilizerViewHolder holder, int position) {

          FertilizerViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemImage());
        FertilizerViewHolder.mTitle.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());
        FertilizerViewHolder.mDescription.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());
        FertilizerViewHolder.mPrice.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());


    }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
        return myFertilizersList.size();
    }
    }

         class FertilizerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder      {

       static ImageView imageView;
       static TextView mTitle;
        static TextView mDescription;
       static TextView mPrice;
        static CardView mCardView;

        public FertilizerViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        mPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myCardView);
       }
        }
```

(recycler_row_item.xml) is here:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5.5">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/ivImage"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:src="@drawable/urea_fertilizer"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1.5">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitle" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Description"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:id="@+id/tvDescription" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rs.300"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:id="@+id/tvPrice" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>

I want to show Title and Description and Price but it shows only title.
```

Answer (score 1):

in onBindViewHolder(), the specific data is assigned to the Views
This is how it should be done.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FertilizerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemImage());
        holder.mTitle.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.mDescription.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.mPrice.setText(myFertilizersList.get(position).getItemName());


    }
```

let me know if that helps you out.

Comment: I can mark it but guide me how I can mark it,Accepted option is not seen here.

Answer (score 0):

Never set it up in onBindViewHolder myself but if you are going to do that you should be like holder.mTitle.setText(""); instead of using the actual class name. You instantiating the holder but then not using it.

Comment: Thanks man , Your Suggestions works for me. Again Thanks a lot.